# Submit from multiple forms

Tags: java, forms, jsf, primefaces, submit

I have several forms in my jsf application and I want to submit from some of them my data to persist the data in the database.

My `xhtml` looks like that:

```
<h:panelGroup id="tempOptionGroup">
<h:form id="tempOptionForm" >
...
</h:form>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:form id="2Form" >
...
</h:form>


<h:panelGroup id="panel">
<h:form id="3Form">
...
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup>

<h:form id="buttonForm">
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
action="#{Bean.callPersist}" style="margin-top:5px"
id="submit" />
</h:form>
```

How to submit all these 3 forms with one `p:commandButton`

**UPDATE**

I looked up some properties of `h:commandButton` and I read that `process=":tempOptionGroup:tempOptionForm"` would process the first form, does this also work with several forms?

Comment: Instead of having all those forms, you can just use one single form right?

Comment: @maximus Did you try `<p:commandButton process="@all"` ?

Comment: @RongNK Thx however, I only want to `process` some forms and not `all`, does `process` has an option so process some forms?

Comment: @maximus right, you can: `<p:commandButton process=":form1_id :form2_id ... "` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY need this, you could do something like submitting the other forms with javascript when the button is clicked (yes, you could do this since your commandButton is ajax submit based), for this you whould use 'onclick' from commandButton and invoque 'submit' with the form object (document.getElementById('formid').submit()). Other than that, I don't think there is really anything that commandButton can natively do for you.

Rough example:

```
    <script>
        function submitOthers(){
            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
            document.getElementById('form2').submit();
        }
    </script>

    <h:form id="form1">
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="form2">
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="form3">
        <p:commandButton onclick="submitOthers()" ></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

In case that refreshes the page, you could (ugly) add hidden commandButton's in each other form and do a similar javascript that would get the buttons and call click() on them. In that case the submit would be ajax.

---

But, since your view seems homogeneous, you could replace your tree forms with a single form, with the button inside (if there is no need for three forms...).

Comment: thx for your answer! my problem is, that I only want to submit some forms and some forms not. Do you have a specific example for a javascipt submit?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** submit multiple forms this way. You need to create a collector form and submit that instead. Look [here](http://www.codetoad.com/forum/15_24387.asp) for more information.